# .JS refuses to enable menu

Tags: jquery, css, html, web

I'm referring to this website to learn how to implement a side menu in CSS: http://purecss.io/layouts/side-menu/

I am not succeeding. I have a **`>`** on the upper part of my webpage, which only appeared after implementing the two source codes provided by the link. It isn't becoming interactive though. To get it responsive, I need to declare the line to enable the `ui.js` code, but I'm having trouble with this. [image: The webpage/]

I declared:

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<!<script type="text/css" src="Scripts/main.css"></script>>
<script src="ui.js"></script>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="ui.js"></script>
        <style>
                body {background-color:black}
                h1   {color:azure}
                p    {color:whitesmoke; border:2px solid whitesmoke; padding: 10px;}
        }</style>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="side-menu.css" media="screen" />
    </head>
    <h1>
        Home
    </h1>
    <p>
        Your momma!
    </p>
    <div>
        <button id="btnAdd" class="btn btn-small">Add</button>
        <button id="btnClear" class="btn btn-small">Clear</button>
    </div>
</html>`
```

And it isn't becoming active. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of **basic** things wrong with your code:

- Where is the **body** tag?
- Script tag outside of the html tag!!!
- Incorrect CSS styles (Extra trailing curly brace)

Answer (score 1):

Your example isn't valid HTML - I'd suggest fixing the bugs and trying again.

You have multiple `<script>` tags pointing to the same file.

HTML tags start with `<tag>` and end with `</tag>`.  Comments begin `<!--` and end `-->`.

When loading CSS, you need to use a `<link>` tag, not a `<script>` tag.

Nothing should exist directly inside the `<html>` tag other than a single `<head>` and a single `<body>`

Your code, tidied up, would look something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Scripts/main.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="side-menu.css" media="screen" />
        <script src="ui.js"></script>
        <style>

body {
    background-color:black;
}
h1 {
    color:azure;
}
p {
    color:whitesmoke;
    border:2px solid whitesmoke;
    padding: 10px;
}

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Home</h1>
        <p>Your momma!</p>
        <div>
            <button id="btnAdd" class="btn btn-small">Add</button>
            <button id="btnClear" class="btn btn-small">Clear</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Proper indentation is important because it helps you spot errors.  For example, in your inline `<style>` element, you had one too many closing braces `}`.  The browser will still try its best to make sense of what you've got, but this kind of "extra brace" can cause all kinds of hard-to-find bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some typos/syntax errors.  Remove the ` at the beginning and end, the first <!, and the second > where there's a >> and try again.

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<!<script type="text/css" src="Scripts/main.css"></script>>
```

Also, the first 2 script tags should be moved into the head section.  And you've got a duplicate script tag for ui.js in there.. so only need one.